# Modification of rsa encrypted cipher text

Tags: encryption, rsa, private-key

I've the following problem:

I use a RSA private key to encrypt a given plain text. I want to send it to another application over an unsecure channel. The other application only knows the public key.

Is it possible for a man in the middle to change parts of the cipher text so that the decryption results in a modified text?

I tried this by myself in my Java application, but if I do so, I always get

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_112]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2048) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

I'm using algorithm "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" in my Java application for encryption and decryption.

Regards

Comment: Depends on which padding algorithm you use. But I don't think padding is intended to be used as an integrity check.

Comment: Which padding algorithm are you using?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: @PeterBruins is correct, pkcs#1 block type 1 padding is not intended to be used as a cryptographic integrity check. It is unlikely that a random change to the output will result in a valid decryption *by the current version of the Oracle provider*, but cryptanalysts are clever and would do something smarter. For example, they might multiply two or more ciphertexts together mod N.

Comment: "I use a RSA private key to encrypt a given plain text.". You should stop [*right there*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172). Encryption with an RSA private key is not signature generation *and* it does not provide confidentiality of the message either; it is not a secure cipher. You encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key, *period*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to the question was given by Maarten Bodewes:

> "I use a RSA private key to encrypt a given plain text.". You should stop right there. Encryption with an RSA private key is not signature generation and it does not provide confidentiality of the message either; it is not a secure cipher. You encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key, period. –